# Segmentation fault (core dumped) in C in mergesort using pointers and linkedlists

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I am having trouble figuring out which line of code produces the segmentation fault (core dumped) error in my code. I am trying to implement mergesort using linkedlists (with pointers). i.e. an in-place solution where the tail pointers are changed to point to something new.

I tried using gdb to debug and tell me which line caused the segmentation fault but it only tells me the address, which I don't think is helpful.

This is the mergesort function:

```
    List *mergesort(List *list) { 
  if (list == NULL || list->tail == NULL) { 
    return list;
  } else { 
    List *list1;
    List *list2;
    split(list, &list1, &list2);
    list1 = mergesort(list1);
    list2 = mergesort(list2);
    return merge(list1, list2);
  }
}
```

The error occurs in the split function:

```
void split(List *list, List **list1, List **list2) { 
  /* TODO */
  printf("split is called\n");
  List * pointer_list1;
  List * pointer_list2;
  List * pointer_traverse1;
  List * pointer_traverse2;
  printf("start");
  pointer_list1 = list;
  pointer_list2 = list->tail;
  list = list->tail;
  int sentinel = 0;
  while(list->tail != NULL){
    printf("entering while loop");
    if(sentinel == 0){
      printf("sentinel equals zero");
      pointer_traverse1->tail = list->tail;
      pointer_traverse1 = pointer_traverse1->tail;
      printf("end of if block");
    }else{
      pointer_traverse2->tail = list->tail;
      pointer_traverse2 = pointer_traverse2->tail;
    }
    list = list->tail;
    if(sentinel == 0 ){
      sentinel = 1;
    }else{
      sentinel = 0;
    }
  }
  printf("END");
  list1 = &(pointer_list1);
  list2 = &(pointer_list2);
  return;
}
```

Note that only the first printf statement ("split is called") is called. The merge function is never called before the error occurs. No other printf in the split function is run. So my natural guess would be that instantiating those pointers to lists produced the segmentation fault, but that's ridiculous because they are just declarations? Is it possible that I ran out of memory somehow?

// This might be helpful to anyone trying to understand split. Essentially, given a list of integers say [1,2,3,4,5,6] I am trying to create a list1 of [1,3,5] and list2 of [2,4,6]. I do this by creating a pointer for list1, another list2, and iterate through list, throwing the numbers into list1 and list2 alternately.

Comment: This code is incomplete. I don't see a single allocation here. Post a [mcve].

Comment: If you ran out of memory then `malloc` returns `NULL`. Is this the case? Do you check that return value?

Comment: Most segmentation fault errors come from exercising an invalid pointer or referencing an invalid array index. Have you stepped through this code in a debugger up to the point of failure?

Comment: compile your code with the `-g` flag, gdb will tell now  you the line it failed on

Comment: @EugeneSh. "I don't see a single allocation here" , maybe thats why it crashes (wink)

Comment: Silly me! I ran the debugger with -g and found the line that crashed it. It turns out I hadn't defined pointer_traverse1 and pointer_traverse2!